# Android sqlite column sum?

Tags: android, sqlite

First Of All i am new to programming currently learning Android .And also this is my first Question over here so pardon if any mistake. The thing is i am stucked in how to get total of database column.
here's my code to retrieve the data from the sqlite helper.

```
private void GetColumnTotal() {
    SQLHelper ColumnTOtal = new SQLHelper(this);
    try {
        ColumnTOtal.open();
        int total = ColumnTOtal.Total();
        ColumnTOtal.close();
        RemainingAmount.setText(""+total);
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

`And heres the code of my sqlite helper . i am posting it all hope you guys help.

```
public class SQLHelper {
public static final String KEY_ROWID = "_id";
public static final String KEY_MONEY = "SpendedMoney";

private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "BudgetDB";
private static final String DATABASE_TABLE = "BudgetTable";
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
private final Context ourContext;
private SQLiteDatabase ourDATABSE;
private DBHelper ourHelper;


public SQLHelper(Context context) {
    ourContext = context;

}

public SQLHelper open() throws SQLException {

    ourHelper = new DBHelper(ourContext);
    ourDATABSE = ourHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    return this;
}

public void close() {
    ourHelper.close();
}

public long createEntry(String money) {
    ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
    cv.put(KEY_MONEY, money);

    return ourDATABSE.insert(DATABASE_TABLE, null, cv);
}

public String getData() {
    String[] columns = new String[]{KEY_ROWID, KEY_MONEY};
    Cursor c = ourDATABSE.query(DATABASE_TABLE, columns, null, null, null, null, null);
    String result = "";


    int iRow = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_ROWID);
    int iName = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_MONEY);

    for (c.moveToFirst(); !c.isAfterLast(); c.moveToNext()) {
        result = result + c.getString(iRow) + " :- " + c.getString(iName) + "\n";
    }
    return result;
}

public int Total() {
    Cursor cur = ourDATABSE.rawQuery("SELECT SUM(SpendedMoney) FROM BudgetTable", null);
    if (cur.moveToFirst()) {
    }
return cur.getInt(0);
}


private static class DBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    public DBHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }


    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + DATABASE_TABLE + "(" +
                        KEY_ROWID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
                        KEY_MONEY + " TEXT NOT NULL);"
        );
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + DATABASE_TABLE);
        onCreate(db);
    }
}
```

Solved!! Thanx everyone. And also the one who downvoted my question.. :)

Comment: `public Cursor Total()` should be `public int Total()`, since you're not returning the whole cursor, but only an integer value.

Comment: If you get an error message, you must show it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error message is not related to SQLite. Somewhere else you are using 0 where a string resource id is expected. One example could be that you display the result using `setText(int)` on a `TextView` instead of `setText(CharSequence)`. The stacktrace should tell you where.

Comment: Thanx! it helped . But the sum i get is 0 dont know why can you help ?

Comment: Are you sure that the table contains data ? What is the result if you replace `SUM(SpendedMoney)` whith `count(*)` ?